# IE9 is not rendering a css style that overwrites a bootstrap navbar class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9, navbar

So I have a class that overwrites .navbar-inner. It works fine in IE10, Chrome, etc. But in IE9 the default .navbar-inner styles are being shown and when using the IE dev tools, there is no mention of my custom class.

Any ideas?

#### LESS

```
.navbar {
  .navbar-inner {
    .logo{
      margin-left:80px;
      .brand {
        background: url("/images/spritesheet.png") no-repeat scroll -71px -236px transparent;
        height: 40px;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        text-indent: -99999em;
        width: 20px;
      }
    }

    background: #494949;
    border: none;      
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 60px;
  }
}
```

#### Import Order

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/employers/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <script src="/javascript/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Bootstrap is being imported at the very top of our styles.css file. We have check to make sure is being imported correctly and before any of our changes to .navbar-inner.

Comment: show the code of those CSS classes and how you apply them.

Comment: show the order in your <head>